# Connecting two computers with ethernet cable

Tags: windows, http, ubuntu, networking

I'm new to networking. I need to transfer a lot of large files from a Windows 10 pc to  Ubuntu 16.04 pc. I connected the two PCs with an ethernet cable and installed http-server for nodejs on Windows 10 pc and started it as follow:

```
http-server E:/ -a 192.168.0.130

Starting up http-server, serving E:/
Available on:
   http://192.168.0.130:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server.
```

On Ubuntu pc I opened my brower (Firefox) and entered 192.168.0.130 without success. How can I achieve connection between the two computers?

Comment: Take a look: http://askubuntu.com/questions/633142/connect-windows-8-1-to-ubuntu-14-04-using-crossover-cable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you configured IP addresses on both computers?  Did you make sure to put them on the same IP network?

Also, if you connect computers directly to each other with an ethernet cable the network interface cards need to be able to detect and correct the fact that you are not using a "cross-over" ethernet cable.  Almost all newer ethernet cards can do this so it probably won't be a problem.

I suspect you have not put IP addresses on the computers.  You will need to do this manually since you are not connecting to a network that is dynamically assigning addresses via DHCP.

Comment: Please avoid asking questions in solutions. You should post a comment instead.